# Modify single field in ES using chewy

Tags: elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I have an index in elastic search, i want to update a single document of the index using chewy in rails 3.2. There is a way to perform this for a tableless model?

I just want to find the document in the index and modify one of the fields.

I spent some hours in the docs and still don't understand how to do that, probably is simplier than i expect.

Thanks

I tried using the CustomIndex.find id to retrieve the document. That worked, but when i tried to update that document using .save or .update i couldn't make it work in any ways.
Also tried with CustomIndex.update_index unsuccessful, but  i actually don't understand how make it work.